# Azure Static WebApp - Is it possible to change the repository after creating the web app?

Tags: azure

When you create an Azure Static Web-app you specify the GIT repository during configuration. GitHub and Azure Devops are the popular options.

I can't seem to find an option to change the repo once it's created.

I'm going to have this repository hooked up to several static web-apps using different custom domain names and suspect I may need to modify the webpages shown for each custom domain at some point in the future.

If that happens I could delete and re-create the web-app or use branching and modify the build config in the branch's YML file, but would probably prefer to spin up a new GIT Repo and point the web-app at that.

Is it possible?

Related question:

- [Change the source "Branch" in Azure Static Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515286/change-the-source-branch-in-azure-static-web-app)

More info on Static Web Apps:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it by following steps

**If need to change repository**

1. Get the workflow yml file from the existing repo
2. And add it to new. Add the secret to the new repo with the same key (secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_...) and the deployment token.
3. Grab the Deployment token from the Azure static web app, Manage deployment token link.

Refer Below screen shot for deployment token

[image]

**If need to change branch**

you can just edit the branch in the yml file, e.g.
azure-static-web-apps-xxx.yml

```
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
      pull_request:
        types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
        branches:
          - main
[...]
```

[Click on this For More Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions)

Comment: That works. I found it best to reset the deployment token on Azure then apply it to the new repo on GitHub (settings>secrets>actions) so only 1 repo targeted the web-app. I pushed changes via Git to update the live site and up they went.